# Login with enter key pressed knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been trying to get my login page to work once I pressed the enter key, but it doesn't work. Help anyone?
Here is my codes:

Javascript/ viewModel:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterkey = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        var callback = valueAccessor();
        $(element).keypress(function (event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                callback.call(viewModel);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};

Mobile.Login = function (params) {
    var viewModel = {
        dxPasswordTB: {
            value: ko.observable(""),
            showClearButton: true,
            placeholder: ko.observable("PASSWORD"),
            mode: 'password'
        },
        validateAndSubmit: function (params) {
            var result = params.validationGroup.validate();
            ...
        },
    };
    return viewModel;
};
```

View/ HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-password"></i></span>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <div data-bind="dxTextBox: dxPasswordTB, dxValidator: PasswordVR, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: validateAndSubmit""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what went wrong here? If you do, please post your suggestions here, thanks!

Comment: have you tried calling `validateAndSubmit` function instead of `callback.call(viewModel);` ?

Comment: @gkb The error I received when I press Enter key is: Login.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validationGroup' of undefined

Comment: @gkb I tried but the error still persist

Comment: Hmmm, so that means `params` is undefined, might be the issue with _what_ is being sent as a parameter to `validateAndSubmit`...keep debugging and share more info as you have them...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by using `onEnterKey`in dxPasswordTB from devExpress. Also, I changed `params.validationGroup.validate();` to `DevExpress.validationEngine.validateGroup()` and the value was finally defined.